# Execute Silverlight 4 Command on Load

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

How do you implement a Silverlight 4 command to execute when the user control loads instead of being mapped to an explicit button click?

Answer (score 4):

Or simply add a [trigger](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/) in xaml for your UserControl:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <si:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: That works nicely but it isn't as simple as that, you need to add the appropriate references which in turn increases the application download size.  If there are various other uses for these references fine but if not then a coded solution avoids the need for additional references for this requirement.

Comment: True, you'll have to reference System.Windows.Interactivity (45K) and Expression.Samples.Interactivity (53K) for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DependencyProperty` of type `ICommand`:-

```
    #region public ICommand LoadedCommand

    public ICommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get { return GetValue(LoadedCommandProperty) as ICommand; }
        set { SetValue(LoadedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "LoadedCommand",
                    typeof(ICommand),
                    typeof(MainPage),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion public ICommand LoadedCommand
```

Also add a something to act as the command parameter:-

```
    #region public object LoadedCommandParameter

    public object LoadedCommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(LoadedCommandParameterProperty) as object; }
        set { SetValue(LoadedCommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "LoadedCommandParameter",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(MainPage),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion public object LoadedCommandParameter
```

Now set up its execution like this:-

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;
    }

    void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoadedCommand != null && LoadedCommand.CanExecute(LoadedCommandParameter))
        {
            LoadedCommand.Execute(LoadedCommandParameter);
        }
    }
```

Now if your ViewModel (has a command called `StartStuff`) then:-

```
  <UserControl1 LoadedCommand="{Binding StartStuff}" .... >
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a load of code. The concise version without the code behind

```
public class LoadedBehaviour
{
   public static ICommand GetLoadedCommand(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (ICommand)dependencyObject.GetValue(LoadedCommandProperty);
   }

   public static void SetLoadedCommand(DependencyObject dependencyObject, ICommand value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(LoadedCommandProperty, value);
   }

   public static Action GetLoadedCommandExecutor(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (Action)dependencyObject.GetValue(LoadedCommandExecutorProperty);
   }

   public static void SetLoadedCommandExecutor(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Action value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(LoadedCommandExecutorProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LoadedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));
   public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandExecutorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LoadedCommandExecutor", typeof(Action), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));

   private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(d is FrameworkElement))
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("Loaded command can only be used on FrameworkElements");
         var executor = GetLoadedCommandExecutor(d);
         if(executor == null)
         {
            executor = () =>
            {
                   var command = GetLoadedCommand(d);
                   command.Execute(e);
         };
            SetLoadedCommandExecutor(d, executor);
            ((FrameworkElement)d).Loaded += (obj, args) => executor();
      }
   }
}
```